# Is the Avery who is Snape's friend a relative of Avery who is in Tom Riddle's circle?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

In Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince when Harry and Dumbledore are in Slughorn's memory they see see Tom Riddle with a bunch of other students in Slughorn's office. Among them are Lestrange and Avery:

> 'Good gracious, is it that time already? You'd better get going, boys, or we'll all be in trouble. Lestrange, I want your essay by tomorrow or it's detention. Same goes for you, Avery.'
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince Pg 463</sup></sub>

In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows when Harry is in Snape's Memory he sees a conversation between Lily and Snape where Lily mentions an Avery:

> '...thought we were supposed to be friends?' Snape was saying. 'Best friends?'
>
> 'We are, Sev, but I don't like some of the people you're hanging around with! I'm sorry, but I detest Avery and Mulciber!...'
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Pg 540</sup></sub>

Tom Riddle and Severus Snape are not in Hogwarts at the same time so my guess is that the second Avery is a son or some relative of the first. Is that right?

Comment: Probably they're related (Rowling does these things), but why son? I am afraid it will be answered as "we don't know". Good question though.

Comment: Yes you have a point.  It should be relative. Son was just the first thing that popped up in mind. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## They’re likely of the pure-blood Avery tree.

Both wizards named Avery and affiliated with the Dark Lord are almost certainly members of the pure-blood Avery family, one of the twenty-eight truly pure-blood families.

> In the early 1930s, a ‘Pure-Blood Directory’ was published anonymously in Britain, which listed the twenty-eight truly pure-blood families, as judged by the unknown authority who had written the book***, with ‘the aim of helping such families maintain the purity of their bloodlines’. The so-called ‘Sacred Twenty-Eight’ comprised the families of:
>
> Abbott
>
> Avery
>
> Black 
> <sub><sup>*[- Pure-Blood (Wizarding World Online)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood)*</sup></sub>

Pure-bloods are one of the groups most likely to join or support the Death Eaters, as the Dark Lord wanted to put pure-bloods in charge, and several of the surnames in the Sacred Twenty-Eight are also found among the ranks of the Death Eaters.

> “Were – were your parents Death Eaters as well?’
> ‘No, no, but believe me, they thought Voldemort had the right idea, they were all for the purification of the wizarding race, getting rid of Muggle-borns and having pure-bloods in charge.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, they’re almost certainly related by being members of the same pure-blood family, though exactly how they are related is not mentioned.